# c# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm getting an error saying:

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'email' of 'Person.Person(string, int, string),

I'm new to this so not sure but help would be thanked, thanks

edit: its the "base" that's highlighted red in my program

```
public class Student : Person
{
    /// <summary>
    /// student ID number
    /// </summary>
    private String Postcode;    // student ID number

    public Student() : base("(unknown name)", 0000)
    {
        Postcode = "(unknown ID)";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a student with given name, year of birth and student ID
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">name</param>
    /// <param name="dateOfBirth">year of birth</param>
    /// <param name="Postcode2">ID</param>

    public Student(String name, int dateOfBirth, String Postcode2, string email) : base(name, dateOfBirth, email)
    {
        Postcode = Postcode2;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// read only poperty for ID
    /// </summary>
    public string PostalCode
    {
        get { return Postcode; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Return a string representation of this object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>string representation of Student object</returns>
    public override String ToString()    // redefined from "Person"
    {
        return base.ToString() +
               "Student Member\n" +
               "Postcode: " + Postcode + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see your `Person` class.

Comment: Seems strange that `dateOfBirth` is represented by an `int` rather than a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

`base` is the `Person` class that `Student` is implementing, and the error means that you're not passing a required parameter to it's constructor (named `email`) when you do:

```
base("(unknown name)", 0000) // This only passes 2 parameters to the Person constructor
```

To fix this you either need to add a constructor to the `Person` class that *doesn't* require an `email`, or pass a default value (like you're doing for `Name`:

```
public Student() : base("(unknown name)", 0, "(unknown email)")
{
    Postcode = "(unknown ID)";
}
```